# Memoization of a Void Method using System.out.println

Tags: java

I am trying to save the system out results of a void method through **memoization**. I am assuming **printstream** is used in some way, but I am unfamiliar with its use.

How do you save the `system.out.println` from its first call to be able to be used again without having to do all the calculations for it again?

An example of a void method using `system.out.println` being saved in a variable to be used again will be helpful as I have never seen it before, but I assume there is a way.

```
public void () {
//calculations
System.out.println("formatted response");
}
```

Comment: The `String` you print is presumably something you could memoize. Without seeing any code, I can't offer more than that. Best of luck!

Comment: I put an example of what I am doing. It is just a void method doing calculations and printing a response formatted. I want to save what is being printed to be memoized

Comment: There is nothing being calculated upon or with, nor does the result depend on anything. A constant `String` (like you have here) isn't memoizable. Show us **real** code.

Comment: Without more code, the general advice: don't print the output in your method, but make your method return a String; memoize the result of the method; and print the result of the memoized method. Follow the single-responsibility-principle - calculating something and printing something are separate responsibilities.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a class that offer this functionality. When you use it to print some text it writes this text in a cache that you can retrieve whenever you like. Here is some example:

```
public class ChachedPrint {

    private static List<String> cache = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void println(String text){
        cache.add(text);
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    public List<String> getCache(){
        return cache;
    }

}
```